# Coustomize Orangehrm Login Process

Tags: php, smarty, autologin, orangehrm

I want to coustomize Orangehrm. This includes a simple change in the login process. I want to get auto login into the Orangehrm when I login into my own website build using smarty. Can anybody tell me where to start off and what I could do to make this change in Orangehrm login process ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by simply passing the external form by jQuery Ajax Call which is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

   var j = jQuery.noConflict();

   function submit_to_two(){
      var username = j('#username').val();
      var password = j('#pass').val();
      var hdnUserTimeZoneOffset = j('#hdnUserTimeZoneOffset').val();

      if(username != '' && password != ''){

        var data_to_send = {
           username: username,
           password: password,
           hdnUserTimeZoneOffset: hdnUserTimeZoneOffset
        };

        j.ajax({
           url : '../orangehrm/symfony/web/index.php/auth/validateCredentials',
          /* url : './orangehrm/process1.php',*/
           type: "POST",
           async: false,
           data : data_to_send,
           success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
           {
              window.open('../orangehrm/symfony/web/index.php/', '_blank');
              j('#loginform').submit();
           },
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
           { 
           }
        });
      }
   }
</script>
```

If somebody wants to get the hdnUserTimeZoneOffset from Orangehrm it self we can do that by sending a get ajax call to the login link it will return the whole form then you could simply extract the hdnUserTimeZoneOffset by using:

```
hdnUserTimeZoneOffset = j(data).find('#hdnUserTimeZoneOffset').val();
```